# Extract data from Python dataframe and insert into print() statement without table format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe that is generated, and using weighted_sample, it extracts 6 numbers based on the likelihood it'll appear (Frequency). An example is below:

```
Numbers  Frequency
      40   2.141527
      25   1.675978
      42   2.793296
      29   1.769087
       5   2.141527
      39   1.862197
```

I want to take the above random numbers that are generated, and put them into a print() statement where it is up to date with whatever 6 random numbers are generated each time. I just don't want it in the table format, if that makes sense - just the 6 numbers.

Comment: Convert the numbers in the table column to a list.

Comment: `print(list(df['animal'].head(6)))` or `print(list(df['animal'].tail(6)))`

Comment: @Luis the OP specifically said they **don't** want it in table format...

Comment: Thanks, @MattDMo, I forgot to put a list there. Regards.